# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, unclear

I wonder how I can improve this question. Unfortunately, I cannot ask it as a comment as the post is locked.

By how, I mean in terms of content (what is unclear?), as well as technically (how can I edit the question since it is locked?)

---

[Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/51980/452)

> Title: Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?
>
> Body: Using a link as a reference is often problematic as the link might disappear at a future time. However, the content might be of high relevance to the reader, so it might be worthwhile to add it as a reference. Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> as well as technically (how can I edit the question since it is locked?)

If a question is locked and you want to edit it, you can flag for a moderator to unlock it.  (Rejected migrations are locked automatically.) I just unlocked this one.

Also, for the record, the close votes on this question were:

- 2x "Unclear what you're asking"
- 2x "Too broad"
- 1x "Shopping question"

Comment: Thanks! Can a user see the vote breakdown?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  No, see [MSE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason). (Moderators, but not users AFAIK, can see the vote breakdown in the [post timeline](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/51980/timeline).)

Comment: Thanks, MSE feature request upvoted.